# How to use Google variable fonts in React-Native

Tags: react-native, fonts, google-fonts

i'm trying to use google custom fonts in react-native but i'm getting issues, i downloaded `OpenSans` font from google and configured it with `react-native` correctly.

font file
`OpenSans-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf`

i'm trying to use it like

```
{
fontSize: 18,
fontFamily:"OpenSans-Bold"
},
```

but i'm getting issue like `Unrecognized font family 'OpenSans-Bold'`. But it is working if i give like `OpenSans-Regular`.

How can i use this file `OpenSans-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf`

Comment: for me i always use expo fonts, and load it on app.js. https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-custom-fonts  but you can also link your .ttf assets to ios or android

Answer (score 0):

This is how have it on mine

```html
<style>@font-face {font-family: "OpenSans-Regular";src: url("OpenSans-VariableFont_wght.ttf");}</style>
```

and for iOS don't forget this to your webview

```js
src={ {html:xxxx, baseUrl: '' }}
originWhitelist={['*']}
```